# I am in need of a batch script that will re-map a network drive

Tags: batch-file

I am in need of a script that will re-map a network drive. I will also need it to be able to enter admin credentials when prompted. The reason I need this script is that I don't want the user to know the password. Currently they have to call me and start a remote session so I can enter the password. This happens about every other day wasting time of both myself and my client. I have found a script that maps the drive (below) but lack the knowledge on how to have it enter the admin credentials.

@echo off
net use S: \Server\Sales

Thanks yall!

Comment: You are aware that a batch file is plain text, which means that the user could read the password? That means that you might as well give the user the password, as you'd be giving it to them anyway by putting it in the batch file.

Comment: 1/ Your configuration is wrong, give users access to the share. 2/ You are saying in your command to only do a temporary mapping. Type `net use help` so see `/persistant`. 3/ Server names start with two slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt window and enter `net use /?` to get help of this command or use the information provided by Microsoft on pages about

- [net use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx) (best)
- [net use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg651155.aspx)
- [net use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx)

As you can read, a password as well as the user credentials can be appended also on the command line. I would have expected that an administrator knows all about that.

The batch file could contain:

```
@echo off
net use S: \\Server\Sales password /user:yourdomain.com\adminusername /persistent:no
```

But it is very unsecure to store the password and the user's / administrator's name in a batch file.

It would be definitely better to change the permissions on the shared folder so that those users who need access to this folder read-only or with write permission have access without mapping the shared folder using administrator credentials.

By the way: What is displayed in square brackets in help output is optional. This is a general rule for any Windows command on which help is output by running this command with `/?` as parameter.